# "Pleasantries" at the start of a question?

Tags: discussion

I haven't been on Worldbuilding much, but I know that on Stack Overflow we're generally against people putting useless text like "Hi, I'm new but I hope you can answer my question.  I love this community and I've been here for a long time but today is my first post, thanks".

[This question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/34157/what-sort-of-problem-would-drive-a-near-omnipotent-civilization-to-seek-an-outs) on Worldbuilding pretty much has this filler and I feel like it shouldn't have the intro paragraph for the following reasons:

- It adds nothing to the question
- Nobody reading the question came to read about the user's personal lurking habits
- It would set a bad precedent for every question to have this kind of text prepended

Comment: I agree with this. Someone should edit that part out.

Comment: Just to be clear, we aren't talking about back stories, right (I love back stories)?

Comment: @PyRulez you can click the link I put and look at the edit history.

Answer (score 6):

You are right.  When I edit questions that have those I delete them (the extraneous sentences) I just don't go and edit them for that alone.  Feel free to clean them up.

Comment: Agreed, and I'd add: try to leave a meaningful edit summary and/or comment so the new user knows *why* this was edited out.

Answer (score 3):

We are usually more lenient than SO on surrounding text, but nevertheless if you do see them, don't hesitate to edit them out. Anyway, your edits will be reviewed.

Answer (score 3):

So I am the new user who posted that question and the accompanying "pleasantries." I was aware that such frivolity is not generally encouraged on SE sites. However, being that I was a new user at the time and also that I have a great love for both the site and the concept it implements, I felt that it would be proper to include the fluff. That kind of thing is just sort of in my nature... I've always been a tad goofy in that way. It was genuine, though, and meant to convey the real sense of camaraderie I feel.

I figured that it would eventually be edited out by a user with the rep and the inclination to do so... and in fact I had planned to edit it out regardless after a small time. It seems as though I was correct in my assumption: it has indeed been edited out. Don't worry; I won't be reversing it. It was, after all, part of my plan. Muahahahah!

Comment: The following two statements contradict each other: 1) I was aware that such frivolity is not generally encouraged. 2) I felt that it would be proper to include the fluff.

Comment: Proper in the sense of honoring my own conscience. No contradiction, just an incomplete statement.

Comment: you always have the option to put some of the niceties in your profile page

Answer (score 1):

I think a comment on the post saying "Our custom is keeping to the question rather than introducing ourselves. That said welcome to the site". Would be friendly and non-aggressive.

Answer (score 0):

If "pleseantries" are very short, I don't think they're a problem. They are only a way being polite and gratefull, if they don't distract from the point of the question and stops after only a few words, in my opinion we don't have to delete them.